# Django Elastic Beanstalk 502 Error Gunicorn No module named application

Tags: python, django, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, gunicorn

I have a django app and im trying to deploy it into aws elastic beanstalk but im getting 502 error from nginx, I have gunicorn installed and listed on my requirements.txt file.

Checking the logs i see the following:

```
Nov 17 20:35:22 ip-172-31-12-36 web: [2021-11-17 20:35:22 +0000] [3510] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 20.1.0
Nov 17 20:35:22 ip-172-31-12-36 web: [2021-11-17 20:35:22 +0000] [3510] [INFO] Listening at: http://127.0.0.1:8000 (3510)
Nov 17 20:35:22 ip-172-31-12-36 web: [2021-11-17 20:35:22 +0000] [3510] [INFO] Using worker: gthread
Nov 17 20:35:22 ip-172-31-12-36 web: [2021-11-17 20:35:22 +0000] [3516] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 3516
Nov 17 20:35:22 ip-172-31-12-36 web: [2021-11-17 20:35:22 +0000] [3516] [ERROR] Exception in worker process
Nov 17 20:35:22 ip-172-31-12-36 web: Traceback (most recent call last):
Nov 17 20:35:22 ip-172-31-12-36 web: File "/var/app/venv/staging-LQM1lest/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 589, in spawn_worker
Nov 17 20:35:22 ip-172-31-12-36 web: worker.init_process()
Nov 17 20:35:22 ip-172-31-12-36 web: File "/var/app/venv/staging-LQM1lest/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/gthread.py", line 92, in init_process
Nov 17 20:35:22 ip-172-31-12-36 web: super().init_process()
Nov 17 20:35:22 ip-172-31-12-36 web: File "/var/app/venv/staging-LQM1lest/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 134, in init_process
Nov 17 20:35:22 ip-172-31-12-36 web: self.load_wsgi()
Nov 17 20:35:22 ip-172-31-12-36 web: File "/var/app/venv/staging-LQM1lest/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 146, in load_wsgi
Nov 17 20:35:22 ip-172-31-12-36 web: self.wsgi = self.app.wsgi()
Nov 17 20:35:22 ip-172-31-12-36 web: File "/var/app/venv/staging-LQM1lest/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 67, in wsgi
Nov 17 20:35:22 ip-172-31-12-36 web: self.callable = self.load()
Nov 17 20:35:22 ip-172-31-12-36 web: File "/var/app/venv/staging-LQM1lest/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 58, in load
Nov 17 20:35:22 ip-172-31-12-36 web: return self.load_wsgiapp()
Nov 17 20:35:22 ip-172-31-12-36 web: File "/var/app/venv/staging-LQM1lest/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 48, in load_wsgiapp
Nov 17 20:35:22 ip-172-31-12-36 web: return util.import_app(self.app_uri)
Nov 17 20:35:22 ip-172-31-12-36 web: File "/var/app/venv/staging-LQM1lest/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gunicorn/util.py", line 359, in import_app
Nov 17 20:35:22 ip-172-31-12-36 web: mod = importlib.import_module(module)
Nov 17 20:35:22 ip-172-31-12-36 web: File "/usr/lib64/python3.8/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
Nov 17 20:35:22 ip-172-31-12-36 web: return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
Nov 17 20:35:22 ip-172-31-12-36 web: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1014, in _gcd_import
Nov 17 20:35:22 ip-172-31-12-36 web: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
Nov 17 20:35:22 ip-172-31-12-36 web: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 973, in _find_and_load_unlocked
Nov 17 20:35:22 ip-172-31-12-36 web: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'application'
Nov 17 20:35:22 ip-172-31-12-36 web: [2021-11-17 20:35:22 +0000] [3516] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 3516)
Nov 17 20:35:22 ip-172-31-12-36 web: [2021-11-17 20:35:22 +0000] [3510] [INFO] Shutting down: Master
Nov 17 20:35:22 ip-172-31-12-36 web: [2021-11-17 20:35:22 +0000] [3510] [INFO] Reason: Worker failed to boot.
```

ANyone has an idea of how to solve it?

Comment: Have you created a `Procfile` in the root of your project?

Comment: @Jarad Yes, also tried adding a Procfile to the root of the folder and same issue, after running `eb deploy` my health goes to degraded. I have to restart the environment and goes again to green health, but shows that error. I'm using python 3.8

Comment: Details provided here are not sufficient to debug the issue, add the contents of the Procfile to your question.

Answer (score 0):

This post worked for me.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/75645678/21749181

Specifically adding a blank .ebignore file

My django.config looks like this

```
option_settings:
  aws:elasticbeanstalk:application:environment:
    DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE: <app name>.settings
    PYTHONPATH: /var/app/current:$PYTHONPATH
  aws:elasticbeanstalk:container:python:
    WSGIPath: <app name>.wsgi:application
  aws:elasticbeanstalk:environment:proxy:staticfiles:
    /static: static
```